# Synchronized, wait and notify in Akka

Tags: concurrency, akka, actor, synchronized

I'd like to ask you a thing. I have one "Rec" actor and more "Sen actors". The first one has a list of messages that must be forwarded and the senders are actors that keep sending messages to Receiver.

Something like this:

```
class Rec (frw: Actor) extends Actor
{
    val myList = Nil;
    def act =
    {
            case "Start" => while(true) {/*Extract the first number and send it to frw*/} //I must use a new actor if I want to keep reading messages
            case i => myList+=i; //Should i use a "synchronize" here (i'm extracting elements with the other actor after all)?
    }
}

class Sen (rcv: Actor) extends Actor
{
    var i=100;
    def act =
    {
            case "Start" => while(i>0) {i+=1; rcv ! i;}
    }
}
```

My problem is that Rec must forward just one message at the time, so it must save all the messages in a list. Is there a way to improve the Rec actor? I don't like the while(true), but i can't extract the first number whenever i receive a message (messages could stay in too long in the list). Should i use synchronized/wait/notify or is there something better for Akka?
Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You should post your code samples here inline

Comment: At the moment the code example you linked doesn't make any sense.  It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish when you say "extract the first number."

Comment: I want to take the first element of the list, remove it from the list and send it to frw.

Comment: Where the requirement to send one message at a time comes from, and what does it really mean? Does it mean that you need to remove a message from the list only after Rec receives an acknowledgment from frw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you do not need the **Rec** actor at all. You will achieve the same result if you send messages from **Sen** to **frw** directly.

You have to rememeber that Akka actors process messages sequentially one after another. So all your messages from **Sen** will arrive to **frw** one message at the time even if you send them directly from **Sen** to **frw**.